# Monoprice MP Mini Delta - How to get started?

Tags: monoprice-mini-delta

I just got a [Monoprice MP Mini Delta](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/monoprice-mini-delta-affordable-starter-3d-printer/x/4856770#/) from an Indiegogo Campaign, but it came with no printed docs.

How do I get started?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Updated Manual

- Turns out an out of date manual was on the sd card that was included with the printer. But it was definitely out of date, as it referenced UI items that don't exist, and files that weren't on the SD card.
- An updated manual can [be found here](https://www.mpminidelta.com/users_manual)
  or [possibly out of date here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gl5vka5un1mkp2g/mini_delta_manual.pdf?dl=0)

### Resources and sample files

- A very helpful [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/mpminideltaowners/) has a [bunch of files](https://www.facebook.com/groups/mpminideltaowners/files/) that are good sample prints. If your manual says you can print a `cat.gcode` you've got an old manual.
- Note: Don't try and just google `cat.gcode` as I did. The model I found rammed the print head right into the bottom of the printer. The correct model works great (actually called auto00.g on the SD card)
- Another great reference site appears to be https://www.mpminidelta.com/, and this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpminidelta/)

### Common Problems and Solutions

The following are some problems I had and their solution

#### Can't print custom models

If you find you can print prebuilt gcodes fine (cat,viking,toothless), but can't seem to print any other models without the print head ramming into the bottom of the printer and going off to the side, you probably haven't setup the autoleveling gcode that's **required**. You can add something like the following line to your software, in a "startup" gcode section. This is detailed in the manual (just search for G29), and [more info can be found here](https://www.mpminidelta.com/g29)

```
; auto-levels the build plate with a overall vertical 
; offset of 0.3mm with a center offset of -0.8mm
G29 C-0.8 Z0.3
```

#### First layer doesnt stick

If you find your first layer isn't sticking, or it seems like the plastic is balling up, you need to adjust your startup gcode line mentioned above , so it has a lower Z offset, like Z0.25 for example

```
G29 Z[offset] ; raises
G29 Z-[offset] ; lowers
```

Notes

- Please try a positive offset value first.
- Each printer will require fine tuning in regards to the offset value.
- Start with a higher value and decrease as necessary to get good first layer adhesion.
- Using a negative offset value may send the nozzle digging into the build plate.

Comment: This is effectively a link-only answer; on its own it does not contain any useful information for someone looking to get started. An answer is supposed to answer the question and, in this case, should help someone get started. You're just pointing the reader to other websites to get the information they need.

Comment: There's lots of info here - manual is on sd card, manual is very out of date, where missing files can be found, sample similar files on the internet cause printer to malfunction. That's information - did you know the answer to those questions before you read this answer? True that this ends up being links as well, but I asked and answered the question as it took me about 45 min to get my printer working by googling and trying to find info, and I would've appreciated this answer myself. Thanks!

Comment: I agree and don't know what the first guy was tlaking about, unless this answer was majorly upgraded.

I mean it even gives gcode to solve a problem.

Comment: In his defense, it has been upgraded as I found more issues that were problematic (gcode being one of them!), but I still thought it was relevant enough to warrant a post ;-)